How can I handle extra commas in columns when importing data from a CSV file to DB using SSIS
Using VS2022 SSIS, I am attempting to import data from a notepad csv file with data like this:
CustomerKey, Name, Address, Country
1001, John, 23 Ave,nue, Australia
1002, Jeff, N,23 West St, Norway

etc...
How can I replace these commas within the Address column with blank space?
I have already tried derived column using REPLACE(Address,",","") and changing my connection managers text qualifier to " but with no luck. Changing the delimiter is not a viable option.
EDIT: This is only regarding SQL Server Integration Services within Visual Studio, using conditionals or derived columns. the CSV file cannot be edited as the task at hand is to remove the extra commas using SSIS tools only.

There is no way to parse that as a CSV properly. The CSV should have quotes around the address. 1001, John, "23 Ave,nue, Austrailia"

If there is only one comma in the address column, you can count and find the position, then replace that number of comma, and lastly import the data.

try to use bcp tool to load. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/load-from-csv-with-bcp?view=azuresql

@EdwinVasquez this isn't practical. How will any script guess which comma is the separator and which comma is part of the address? Or the country field?

to remove the extra commas using SSIS tools only did your manager think through this? If your company cleans up this non-CSV file, it's your company that's liable for any problems and has to pay compensation or fines

*.csv/txt flat files always have host of problems where column delimiters, column separators, invisible characters like null terminators \0, special characters based on encoding, and line breaks are in the middle of the actual data. Or data elements are missing completely, i.e. column positions will vary.
The most reliable format for data feeds is XML enforced by an XSD. An XSD plays a role of a data contract between sender and receiver. It will guarantee proper data format/shape, data types, cardinality, and enforce data quality.

Hi @PanagiotisKanavos, the script did not guess, we told the script what number of comma to remove, and it's easy knowing the position of that comma because in this example is always the third, using the index you can remove it.

That's a guess based on past data that will break on the next unexpected value, like 2 commas in the address or a newline. It's also against the definition of both what a CSV is and what delimited files are supposed to be in general. In situations like these applications either use an uncommon character as a separator, eg | or §  or a tab, or quote the strings. Tabs are so common that the tsv extension stands for Tab Separated Values.

@EdwinVasquez why not just fix the actual problem by using the easy solutions people have been using for the last 50 years? If you can't follow the CSV spec, use a tab.

If you can export the data again somehow, you need quotes around the address.
if you can't do that, and you are limited to SQL, you can try something like this:

Edit the first line to include several more columns:
ID, Name, Address, Address2, Address3, Address4
Import into a temporary table that has all 6 of those columns defined.
Update the temporary table to prefix ,  to Address2, Address3, Address4 where they are defined: update temptable SET Address2 = CONCAT(', ', Address2) WHERE Address2 IS NOT NULL. Do for each address column.
INSERT...SELECT into your target table, from the temporary table, with something like this (sorry, syntax is pseudocode, not sure exact syntax with SSIS):
INSERT INTO mytable (ID, Name, Address) SELECT ID, Name, CONCAT(Address,Address2,Address3,Address4) from temptable


UPDATE
as alternative approach you can load csv as set of rows and parse rows in sql as you want
for SSIS package use bulk isert : here

drop table if exists #TEXTFILE_1
CREATE TABLE #TEXTFILE_1(
    FIELD1 varchar(2000) ,
);

BULK INSERT #TEXTFILE_1 FROM 'C:\1\text.csv'
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR =' | ',ROWTERMINATOR ='0x0a', FIRSTROW=2)

select* from #TEXTFILE_1





FIELD1




1001, John, 23 Ave,nue, Australia


1002, Jeff, N,23 West St, Norway



so i took your example, made some adjustments to show how to load with quotes
P.s.> your example have missing COLUMN NAME.
csv example
CustomerKey, Name, Address, Country
1001, John Doe,23 Ave, Australia
1002,mike john,"23 West St, apt 101",Norway

query:
drop table if exists dbo.TestLoad 
GO
create table dbo.TestLoad (CustomerKey int, Name varchar(50), Address varchar(50), Country varchar(20))
 
-- import the file
BULK INSERT TestLoad
FROM 'c:\1\text2.csv'
WITH
(
        FORMAT='CSV',
        FIRSTROW=2,
        ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'
)

select * from TestLoad


result:



CustomerKey
Name
Address
Country




1001
John Doe
23 Ave
Australia


1002
mike john
23 West St, apt 101
Norway



related to originaly provided data (acc column at the end):

add column to table
create table dbo.TestLoad (CustomerKey int, Name varchar(50), Address varchar(50), Country varchar(20), GHOSTCOLUMN varchar(50))

and result would be as expected:

in addition, usually csv exporting columns with comas wrapped in double quotes (see my example).

Appreciate the comment but please note I'm inserting the data using SSIS  (SQL Server Integration Services) only via Visual Studio 2022, not directly via queries. This is for an assessment and the original csv data cannot be changed as the task is to remove the extra commas via derived columns and conditionals

its fine. but you have BROKEN CSV - nothing will work there unless you wrap text with internal coma with quotes., you can try to parse line by line... that would be crazy.

this article might help you https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6149/import-text-and-csv-files-into-sql-server-database-with-ssis-script-task/

Your source file looks broken. I believe it may contain more additional commas at random places at least in address column, right? I do not have any solution for this issue other than to have the source file delivered in correct format. If your task is exactly to fix the broken file, well... In this case for sure you would need to write a more complicated script task than just a simple transform. Such sources are evil, if you waste your time with such things, next time you will get a file without commas at all or whatever.
OK ok, to fix exactly your issue I would count as address everything between second and last comma. Of course only if your country column is not infected by the same issue. Otherwise you lost.
